# Amongst many but not so

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

You are in a room amongst many. But yet not so, alone yet accompanied. Maybe not physically but mentally. A pale dim light fills the room as you gaze upon the myriad of people in the room. Where are you?

> Hint: Room, Enclosed.

Comment: [logic-puzzle] is only for puzzles requiring logical deduction. Please check tag wikis before using tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in

> [A room of mirrors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_mirrors) as that in [Enter the Dragon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070034/)

**Explanation:**
You are in a room amongst many. But yet not so, alone yet accompanied.  Maybe not physically but mentally.

> My "reflections" are images produced in the mirror, I am actually alone but not so as I can see lots of 'me', everywhere.

A pale dim light fills the room as you gaze upon the myriad of people in the room.

> It's the time of dawn and as the sunlight just entered the room, I woke up to see that it is in fact my [reflection](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8227/a-mirror-flips-left-and-right-but-not-up-and-down)! (and not the case that someone has cloned multiple copies of me).